# How can I use youtubeinmp3 in my app?

Tags: java, android, download, mp3

I want to create an mp3 downloader application,After some research i found a solution which is **YoutubeinMp3 API** but I don't know how can i use this api. API official link is as follow https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/api/

Comment: This is not a question you should answer here. You want something complex and you're asking for an example? Do you even have programming experience?

Comment: Do you even have googling experience?

Comment: Yes, just i need know how can i use API of the youtubeinmp3.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are getting downvotes because it's expected thing to **show code of what you've tried** so others can see why your program is not working and advise (see : [**`How to Ask`**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Ask here when you've started and are stuck on specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I need know how can I use API of the youtubeinmp3... Can you give me an example?"*

The [**API link**](https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/api/) you provided is *the manual* with example. Scroll down to **Direct Links** section an read that for reference (the `fetch` part of URL gives you the MP3 data). You simply access your link as:

```
https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345
```

where you replace the `12345` with actual **video ID** for required video (eg: `iOWamCtnwTc`). Example :

```
https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOWamCtnwTc
```

And it will return the bytes of mp3 (in desktop browser testing this will begin downloading to hard drive). So in Android you simply receive the bytes to a `ByteArray` and then save those bytes as file in your storage location.

You can check some tutorials like [Download from Internet and save to SD](http://androidsnips.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/download-from-internet-and-save-to-sd.html) but actually any tutorial about saving file from internet (whether image or MP3 or whatever) can be adjusted to instead use your the API link as download source.